# How to generate random float in lua?

Tags: random, lua

I need to generate random **float** in Lua. It needs to be > 1, so math.random() is not a solution.

How can I do this?

Comment: Oh, I forgot to say: I need float > 1, so, math.random() not is sollution.

Comment: `math.random() + 1`?

Comment: Just use `math.random` and add 1 to it!

Comment: OMG, exactly...
I need to go sleep :D
Thank you!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This should generate random floats between 1 (inclusive) and 100 (exclusive)

```
math.random() + math.random(1, 99)
```

Comment: math.random(1, 100) will do the same

Comment: @Stomp `math.random(1,100)` generates random _integers_ within that range, not floats.

Answer (score 13):

You can also use something like this to get a number between `lower` and `greater`

```
function randomFloat(lower, greater)
    return lower + math.random()  * (greater - lower);
end
```

Comment: It still could be helpfull for people that find this question

Comment: This helped me out tremendously.  Thanks for posting!

Answer (score 3):

Just posting for fun, but you can use math.random() with no arguments to do this :P

```
print(math.floor((math.random()*100)+0.5))
```